# How can I fix my source code in my C++ program called Flix for Fun Profit Report?

Tags: c++, debugging

I have coded a program in C++ for an assignment in my C++ Intro class but I have multiple errors in the program but I can't seem to figure out how to get all of the bugs out.

The program is supposed to ask the user for the name of the movie, the number of adult and child tickets sold, and calculate the gross box office profit, net box office profit and the amount paid to the distributor.

I can't seem to figure out how to initialize the variables adultTicketPrice and
childTicketPrice and I thought I declared them and am trying to figure out if they need to get initialized if I already declared them?

And how is the childTicket price out of scope?

And why am I getting the other errors and how can I fix them?

```
// Michael VanZant
// Flix for Fun Profit Report

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Create all double variables
    double adultTicketsSold, childTicketsSold, grossBoxProfit, netBoxProfit, 
    amtPaidDist, adultTicketPrice, childTicketPrice

    adultTicketPrice = 12;
    childTicketPrice = 7;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    // Create the string variable
    string movieName;

    // Get the name of the movie and store it in the movieName string
    cout << "What is the name of the movie?";
    getline(cin, movieName);
    cout << "\n";

    // Cin.ignore to ignore the string variable type
    cin.ignore();

    // Get the amount of adult and child tickets sold
    cout << "How many adult tickets do you want to buy?";
    cin >> adultTicketsSold;
    cout << "\n";
    cout >> "How many child tickets did you want to buy?";
    cin >> childTicketsSold;
    cout << "\n";

    // Calculate the amount of gross box office profit and display it
    grossBoxProfit = (childTicketsSold * childTicketPrice) + (adultTicketsSold * adultTicketPrice);
    cout << "Gross Box Office Profit: $" << grossBoxProfit;
    cout << "\n";

    // Calculate the net box profit amount and display it
    netBoxProfit = grossBoxProfit * .20;
    cout << "Net Box Profit Amount: $" << netBoxProfit;
    cout << "\n";

    // Calculate the amount paid to distributor and display it
    amtPaidDist = grossBoxProfit - netBoxProfit;
    cout << "Amount Paid to Distributor is: $" << amtPaidDist;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *declared* != *initialized*. You're also missing some `;` characters in the code you posted. And *all the other errors* when you include absolutely no error messages in your post is not a problem description.

Comment: I did see the ; errors in my code and thanks for pointing that out for me. When you say that there are no error messages in my post, meaning that I need to put them in the text body of my post?

Comment: @SeanV: Well otherwise we have to guess what they are. Don't know why you'd keep them to yourself?

Comment: Fortunately, as you can see from the below, I've become rather good at guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compiler says "expected initialiser", it has nothing to do with these lines:

```
adultTicketPrice = 12;
childTicketPrice = 7;
```

which are actually *assignments*, not initialisations (though some old C terminology would call the first assignment an initialisation).

No, it's because it thinks you're still on this line, providing declarations and (optionally) initialisers:

```
double adultTicketsSold, childTicketsSold, grossBoxProfit, netBoxProfit, 
amtPaidDist, adultTicketPrice, childTicketPrice
```

That's because you didn't put a `;` at the end of it.

Also:

```
cout >> "How many child tickets did you want to buy?";
```

You meant `<<`.

Fixing those two little typos, the code compiles.

Comment: I don't understand why you've used `cin.ignore();` (and the comment above it doesn't make much sense, either). It means I have to add a random input before the ticket quantities. Otherwise, works well good job! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09117e1cb719cd13

Comment: By the way, ask your professor for me to stop teaching people to use floating-point for currency, would you please?

Comment: What would you recommend that  I use instead?

Comment: @SeanV: Regarding currency, you should continue following your professor's course material, but I do wish they wouldn't teach it like this. Currency should be in fixed-point; it solves a gazillion problems and costs (lol) nothing. Integer pennies will often suffice; otherwise tenths of pennies.

Comment: @SeanV: Regarding the `cin.ignore()`, I don't know, I'd just remove it. You'd have to think about why you put it in there — from my POV we're back to guessing on this one.

Comment: Ok, got it. Also, I will have to include all of the errors in my program next time.

Comment: may be also change adult and child type to integers instead of double cant visualize taking a ticket for 1.8796 adults and 3.1415 children btw a declaration and assignment can happen like double foo = 14; instead of double foo ; foo = 14; and i would say using << endl ; is more like c++ instead of cout << "\n"

Comment: @blabb: Actually `cout << "\n"` (or even `cout << '\n'`) is preferable unless you _need_ the added flushing. The rest, you're right.